# r-loops-`*tmp*` subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, subscript

I am using slove.QP to solve a quadratic problem (asset allocation problem). I have four constraints on different ranges of expected returns. For example, for the return range from 6.1 to 6.5, I put a constraint on this range, for range from 6.6 to 7.0, I put another constraint on it, etc.

I create a constraint matrix, it looks like this:

```
min max min max min max min max
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
......
```

mincons in the loops contains all the min columns of the constraints matrix, maxcons contains all the max columns of the constraints matrix.

For example, for the first loop, expected return range from 6.1 to 7.0, I use mincons[,1] and maxcons[,1] in the solve.QP function as constraints. Same thing apply to the next three loops.

But R keeps giving me "subscript out of bounds" error. I've read some similar questions on stackoverflow, but I still cant figure out why I met this error. Can anyone help me with that. Thanks.

```
You can download dataconstraints.csv and datacorrelations.csv at 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bosunahysdfpcj/dataconstraints.csv
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vb94obm83lttdej/datacorrelations.csv

library(quadprog)

mydata = read.csv("dataconstraints.csv") 
er <- matrix(mydata[,1], nrow=23, ncol=1)
stdevs <- matrix(mydata[,2], nrow=23, ncol=1) 
min <- mydata[,c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)]
mincons <- as.matrix(sapply(min, as.numeric))
max <- -mydata[,c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
maxcons <- as.matrix(sapply(max, as.numeric))

mycorr = read.csv("datacorrelations.csv")
correlation <- mycorr
b <- stdevs %*% t(stdevs)  
covariance <- b * correlation

dvec <- er
Dmat <- as.matrix(sapply(covariance, as.numeric))

A.Equality <- matrix(c(1), nrow=length(er), ncol=1)
Amat <- cbind(A.Equality, er, diag(length(er)),-diag(length(er)))

port_ret1 = NULL
bvec1 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=48)
w1 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=23)
sd1 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)
ret1 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)

port_ret2 = NULL
bvec2 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=48)
w2 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=23)
sd2 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)
ret2 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)

port_ret3 = NULL
bvec3 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=48)
w3 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=23)
sd3 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)
ret3 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)

port_ret4 = NULL
bvec4 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=48)
w4 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=23)
sd4 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)
ret4 = matrix(data=NA, nrow=5, ncol=1)

n <- (8.0-6.1)/0.1+1

for(i in 1:n){

  if(i>=1 & i<=5){
    port_ret1[i]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec1[i,] <- c(1, port_ret1[i], mincons[,1], maxcons[,1])
    w1[i,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec1[i,], meq=1)$solution
    sd1[i,] <- sqrt(w1[i,] %*% Dmat %*% w1[i,])
    ret1[i,] <- w1[i,] %*% er
  }

  if(i>=6 & i<=10){
    port_ret2[i]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec2[i,] <- c(1, port_ret2[i], mincons[,2], maxcons[,2])
    w2[i,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec2[i,], meq=1)$solution
    sd2[i,] <- sqrt(w2[i,] %*% Dmat %*% w2[i,])
    ret2[i,] <- w2[i,] %*% er
  }

  if(i>=11 & i<=15){
    port_ret3[i]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec3[i,] <- c(1, port_ret3[i], mincons[,3], maxcons[,3])
    w3[i,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec3[i,], meq=1)$solution
    sd3[i,] <- sqrt(w3[i,] %*% Dmat %*% w3[i,])
    ret3[i,] <- w3[i,] %*% er
  }

  if(i>=16 & i<=20){
    port_ret4[i]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec4[i,] <- c(1, port_ret4[i], mincons[,4], maxcons[,4])
    w4[i,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec4[i,], meq=1)$solution
    sd4[i,] <- sqrt(w4[i,] %*% Dmat %*% w4[i,])
    ret4[i,] <- w4[i,] %*% er
  }
}


Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = c(1, 6.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

error looks like this, so I guess the second if statement is out of bounds. If I run the first if statement only, it runs okay, with no error. I just cant see any problem of out of bounds.

Comment: Your code is not executable - please update it to include `mincons`, `maxcons`, `Dmat`, and double check to make sure nothing else is missing. You should also add `library(quadprog)` at the top since your example uses the function `solve.QP`. In the future, you should test your code in a fresh `R` session before posting it to make sure that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just added everything in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your code is fairly long so I did not read through and try to understand the concept behind it, but I made some adjustments to the content of your `for` loop and it executes without error. The problem was that each of your subgroups `port_ret1` thru `port_ret4`, `bvec1` thru `bvec4`, etc... all have an index length of 5, and you were trying to use `i = 1:20` (since `n=20`) to index values in them. This is fine for the first group - `port_ret1, bvec1, ...`, but when you get to `i=6`, you cannot do `port_ret2[i] <- some value`, because `port_ret2[6]` does not exist; i.e. *the subscript is out of bounds*. So I essentially just shifted back `i` in each subsequent group by the appropriate amount (only where it is used as an index, e.g. not in `<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)`):

```
for(i in 1:n){
  ##
  if( i <= 5){

    port_ret1[i]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec1[i,] <- c(1, port_ret1[i], mincons[,1], maxcons[,1])
    w1[i,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec1[i,], meq=1)$solution
    sd1[i,] <- sqrt(w1[i,] %*% Dmat %*% w1[i,])
    ret1[i,] <- w1[i,] %*% er
  } else if( i <= 10 ){

    port_ret2[i-5]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec2[i-5,] <- c(1, port_ret2[i-5], mincons[,2], maxcons[,2])
    w2[i-5,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec2[i-5,], meq=1)$solution
    sd2[i-5,] <- sqrt(w2[i-5,] %*% Dmat %*% w2[i-5,])
    ret2[i-5,] <- w2[i-5,] %*% er
  } else if( i <= 15 ){

    port_ret3[i-10]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec3[i-10,] <- c(1, port_ret3[i-10], mincons[,3], maxcons[,3])
    w3[i-10,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec3[i-10,], meq=1)$solution
    sd3[i-10,] <- sqrt(w3[i-10,] %*% Dmat %*% w3[i-10,])
    ret3[i-10,] <- w3[i-10,] %*% er
  } else {

    port_ret4[i-15]<-6.1+0.1*(i-1)
    bvec4[i-15,] <- c(1, port_ret4[i-15], mincons[,4], maxcons[,4])
    w4[i-15,] <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec4[i-15,], meq=1)$solution
    sd4[i-15,] <- sqrt(w4[i-15,] %*% Dmat %*% w4[i-15,])
    ret4[i-15,] <- w4[i-15,] %*% er
  }
  ##
}
```

Also, you should use `if...else if...else` statements rather than chain together standalone `if` statements with redundant condition checking. For instance, in the second statement, you do not have to check `if(i >= 6 & i <= 10)` because this condition will be reached **if and only if** `i >= 6` (because of your first `if(i <= 5)` condition). Anyways, this does execute without an error, but like I said, I did not take the time to conceptually understand the task it is accomplishing, so if there is something else that needs to be adjusted let me know.

Comment: Now I know where I did wrong. Thank you so much for your answer. You are awesome!